# My Firebase is not generating token for my app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I request a token from my firebase, but it returns null, I don't know why, but when I check the logs I can see my token there.
So what I can do?

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {

        tokenId = instanceIdResult.getToken();
    }
});
```

Comment: How/where do you check for nullity? Show us the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "get Instance Id failed", task.getException());
                                return;
                            }

                            // Get new Instance ID token
                            String token = task.getResult().getToken();                             
                        }
```

});